# iptables rule for local network on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, iptables

I have this firewall rule on an Ubuntu 20.04 laptop:

```
# cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state ! --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

but if I use this, I cannot print.

Probably the rules prevent some communication between the printer and router.

If these rules are not there and everything is ACCEPT, then whenever I power on the network laser printer, Ubuntu automatically adds it and the printing works.

**Question**: what rules should I put to these firewall rules to make the printer work?

Printer is an HP 1536dnf